# cant separate properly through preg_split

Tags: php, html, html-table

So i have log file like

```
03.02.14 11:16:55 1671 303       00:00:37 6599990                  2  
03.02.14 11:19:03 1671 303       00:00:37 6599990                  2  
04.02.14 09:34:06 1670 303 00:03 00:00:05 06865500                 1
```

Code that reads it and puts it into a page

```
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach (preg_split("/ +/", $line, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY) as $value) { 
        $lineList[$lineNum][$wordNum] = $value;
        $startTS = date_create_from_format('j.m.y', $_REQUEST['datefrom']);
        $endTS = date_create_from_format('j.m.y', $_REQUEST['dateto']);
            $checkTS = date_create_from_format('j.m.y', $lineList[0][0]);

        if (($checkTS >= $startTS) && ($checkTS <= $endTS)){
            echo "<td class='empty'>$value</td>";

        $wordNum++;

     } 
    } echo "</tr>";
```

So as you can see there are multiple spaces in log file but it does not recognise them and dont write a blank cell.
[result from page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnsJe.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex to put every item in its own index of array

```
^(\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2})\s(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\s(\d+)\s(\d+)\s(\d{2}:\d{2}|\s+)\s(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\s(\d+)\s+(\d+)
```

**[demo](https://regex101.com/r/jX4aC9/7)**